# How to create a custom hook, that works like setState in a class component in React with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a custom hook, that updates the state, instead of replacing the state, the same, as setState in class components does. It should work like this:

*part of the render:*

```
interface IExample {
  foo: number
  bar: string
}

const [state, setState] useCustomHook<IExample>({foo: 1, bar: 'aaa'})
```

*in some callback:*

```
setState({bar: 'bbb'}) // after everything settles, the state should be: {foo: 1, bar: 'bbb'}
```

Attempted solution (corrected, works now):

```
const isFunction = (value: any): value is Function => typeof value === 'function'

export default <T>(initialState: T | (() => T)):[T, (newState: Partial<T> | ((prevState: Partial<T>) => Partial<T>)) => void] => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<Partial<T>>(initialState)

  const setStateMerging = (newState: Partial<T> | ((prevState: Partial<T>) => Partial<T>)) => {
    if (isFunction(newState)) {
      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, ...newState(prevState) }))
    } else {
      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, ...newState }))
    }
  }

  return [state, setStateMerging]
}
```

**[Here is a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sousestatemerging-5wwtn)**

The problem is corrected after @Jonas Wilms answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `isFunction` needs to be a typeguard:

```
 const isFunction = (value: any): value is Function => typeof value === 'function'
```